# Silverlight, CGI, and the Debugger

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, cgi

I've got a Silverlight app that has to accept some initial data when it fires up. That data, unfortunately, MUST come from XML input.

In addition, I can't just pass it through the URL because the actual request is coming from a server external to my own.

So the basic setup is this:
Remote server needs to launch my app.
Remote server pops open a window on the user's PC with a URL directed at a CGI application that can accept the XML input.
The CGI app parses the input and spits out an HTML page containing the Silverlight app with all of the init params set.

Long story short: When the Silverlight app is opened this way I can't debug it. I attach to the process, but none of the break points can be hit.

Any ideas?

***Note:***
I tried every way in the world to get the ASP.NET page that would normally host the Silverlight app to accept the XML in the URL but it would get stripped by ASP.NET because of security reasons and no amount of modifying the config file would fix it (since it was stemming from the other web server presumably).

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions, no guarantees:

- Try it with a couple different browsers. I've seen issues debugging on Firefox that weren't replicatable on IE, and vice versa.
- Make sure that "Silverlight" debugging is selected when attaching to the browser.
- If you're attaching to IE 7+, there are (at least) two different processes available, and only one of them will work. In my experience, it's usually the first one listed in the "Attach" dialog box, but you'll want to try all of 'em.
- Make sure that you don't "Web" debugging selected in the web project associated with the page hosting your Silverlight app, and *do* have "Silverlight" debugging selected.